# How to find a string that does not contain a specific string in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to filter out those strings in a list of strings which do not contain a specific substring (which is nothing but today's date in the YYYY-MM-DD format in my case), but unable to do so.

This is what I have tried so far.

My String is in this format - ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-**20180215**.log

The string may also be in this format - ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-**20180215**-1.log (the 1 before .log may go on up to infinite)

If I see that the string is ending with today's date at the end (before .log or -.log), I need to find it.

So, since it is not ending with today's date, I need to filter this out.

I have tried this pattern to identify the file which contains today's date, but I am unable to find that string which does not contain it

```
(.*?)-20180221-?(\\d+)?.log
```

This is one of the patterns I have tried without luck

```
(.*?)-^((?!20180221))-?(\\d+)?.log
```

Comment: Read something about `lastIndex` method in the class `String`, combine it with `subString`

Comment: I am trying to use regex to achieve this @zlakad. I have many other ways in my mind using String APIs, but I would like to do it with regex

Comment: Try this one : `^.*20180215(-\\d+)?\\.log$`

Comment: regex is very inefficient for this task.

Comment: Why using regex, when something is (IMHO) easier without regex? But, it's your choice. Good luck, friend.

Comment: What about [`^(?!.+20180215).+`](https://regex101.com/r/UsqSCS/1) ?

Comment: None of them worked :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept some reasonable limit on the number of digits, then you could use a basic negative lookbehind, like this:

```
String pattern = ".*(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$";
String false1 = "ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180215.log";
String false2 = "ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180215-1.log";
String true1 = "ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180216.log";
String true2 = "ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180216-1.log";

System.out.println(false1.matches(pattern)); // false
System.out.println(false2.matches(pattern)); // false
System.out.println(true1.matches(pattern)); // true
System.out.println(true2.matches(pattern)); // true
```

I would like to point out that if the trailing counter is allowed to have more than 7 digits then it creates an ambiguous situation based on the algorithm you have outlined, because at that point there is no way to distinguish between the counter 20180215 and the date 20180215.

---

**Question Evolution #1**

The question writer has used the comment section on this answer to change his requirements as follows:

> the string should contain "TEST"

**Answer**

You would just add `.*TEST` to the front of the pattern in this answer. Like so:

```
String pattern = ".*TEST.*(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$";
```

---

**Question Evolution #2**

The question writer has used the comment section on this answer to change his requirements as follows:

> to pick up the String which does NOT contain TEST and which does NOT contain today's date

**Answer**

You could use a negative lookahead of "TEST" for every repetition of the initial wildcard, like so:

```
String pattern = "((?!TEST).)*(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)";
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. This helps me to an extent. But I have one more condition to be satisfied. What if I have to say that the string should contain "TEST" for sure and then not contain today's date?

I have tried it this way, but it is not matching.
(.*?)(TEST)(.*?)-(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$

Comment: @Ravi that's a pretty simple alteration. You would just add `.*TEST` to the front of the pattern in this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I have tried with the regex `.*TEST(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$`, but it's returning me false. Can you please let me know what the issue is?

Comment: that worked after changing it as follows: `.*TEST.*(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$`

However, now I have a new requirement. I should also be able to pick up the String which does NOT contain TEST and which does NOT contain today's date.

I tried this pattern, but didn't work though - `.*(?<!TEST).*(?<!20180215(-[0-9]{1,7})?\\.log)$` when tried with the String `ABC-NOTST.20181206.20181208-20180216.log`. It is still returning true here

Comment: @Ravi please see my updated answer. I have responded to two evolutions of your question now. **[Post a new question if you do have a new question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “russian doll questions” are not quite welcome")** Do not use followup comments to ask new questions if the original question was already solved.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Learnt something being new to Stackoverflow. I haven't tried your updated regex though. Should I be providing my comments here for the updated regex test? Or should I create a separate thread?

Comment: @Ravi if it doesn’t work, please let me know. However, if it works but you have a new question, then first [Accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer, next post the new question separately. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark ✔ beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my timezone, it is still the 14th of february, so I used:

```
egrep -- "-$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d now+1day )-?.log" sample
My String is in this format - ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180215.log
```

Well - you're using Java? Why not?

```
-> import java.util.Date
-> Date d = new Date()
-> String today = String.format ("%tY%tm%td", d, d, d)
-> String s1 = "My String is in this format - ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180214.log"
-> String s2 = "The string may also be in this format - ABC-TEST.20181206.20181208-20180214-1.log (the 1 before .log may go on up to infinite)"
-> String pattern = ".*" + today + "\\.log"
-> s1.matches (pattern) 
|  Expression value is: true
|    assigned to temporary variable $39 of type boolean
-> s2.matches (pattern) 
|  Expression value is: false
|    assigned to temporary variable $40 of type boolean
```

That's copied from the jshell, a fine tool, for fast ad hoc testing.

```
 (.*?)-20180221-?(\\d+)?.log
```

Well compared with today - be it the 14th or the 15th - we don't want to be to strict about it, but 02/21 is pretty off, isn't it?

What is the first question mark supposed to do?

Can the fine line be

```
   -20180221.log
   -20180221-.log
   -20180221888.log
   -20180221-888.log
```

? 
If lines don't match - do you still need to find those, which contain

or isn't it either

```
   -20180221.log
```

or
       -20180221-888.log

Then:

```
   String pattern = ".*" + today + "(-[0-9]+)?\\.log";
```

If there might be something behind log:

```
   String pattern = ".*" + today + "(-[0-9]+)?\\.log.*";
```

Comment: the pattern is either 20180221.log or 201802221-1.log